# How to do round-robin queries to multiple nodes in a CrateDB cluster from pgx?

Tags: go, cratedb

I'd like to connect to multiple nodes in a [CrateDB](https://github.com/crate/crate) cluster from [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx) and execute queries in a round robin fashion.

Ideally if a node fails queries would be retried on the other nodes.

There's a [client in Python that supports clustering](https://github.com/crate/crate-python) but only found PGX for Go from the supported clients page: https://crate.io/docs/crate/clients-tools/en/latest/

Comment: I think PGX does support adding multiple hosts, however not to be used in a round robin fashion, but rather only for failover. You would need to write your own function on top of it, handling multiple connections or use a load balancer for the cluster.

https://github.com/jackc/pgx/pull/545